# Is the operator norm of the Jacobian matrix the right norm for obtaining the Lipschitz constant of $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, lipschitz-functions

The question is as in the title.

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth mapping and denote its Jacobian matrix at each $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ as $(Df)(x)$.

By assumption, $(Df)(x)$ is a $n \times n$ square matrix and itself a smooth mapping from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$.

Let us further assume that the "operator norm" of $[Df](x)$ with respect to the Euclidean norm of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded by $1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$:
\begin{equation}
\lVert (Df)(x) \rVert_{operator} \leq 1 \text{ for all } x \in \mathbb{R}^n.
\end{equation}

Then, is it true that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous with the modulus of continuity bounded by $1$? That is,
\begin{equation}
\lVert f(x)-f(y) \rVert \leq \lVert x-y \rVert
\end{equation}
for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$? Here $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ is the Euclidean norm of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I strongly suspect that the "operator norm" is the correct matrix norm for estimating the modulus of Lipschitz continuity for vector-valued functions, but I have trouble justifying my belief rigorously..

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Yes, use the integral formula, $f(y) = f(x) + \int_0^1 Df(x(1 - t) + yt)(y - x) \, dt$.